# VBA error when opening shared file - reading tags is treated as attempt to modify

Tags: vba, tags, powerpoint, office-2010

I have come across a strange error and am looking for some insights.

**Scenario:**

A powerpoint file on a shared drive is opened by user A. User B now wants to open the same file, and is presented with a "open as read only?" dialog. User clicks "OK".

The file is opened, and an add-in runs (whenever a file is opened) to check for certain tags on slides, indicating presence of confidential material. This causes an error in the following function:

```
Function taggedSlide(tagName As String)
' find the slide which is tagged with tagName
Dim oSl As Slide

Set oSl = Nothing

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
  If Len(oSl.Tags(tagName)) > 0 Then        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this is the line that causes error
    Set taggedSlide = oSl
    Exit Function
  End If
Next oSl
Set taggedSlide = Nothing
End Function
```

The function ostensibly loops over all slides in the presentation, looks for a tag called `tagName`, and returns the slide (or Nothing). It *looks* like this only involves "read" operations, but the code throws an error at the indicated line.

To make things more interesting, the behavior is *different* if I simply mark a file as "read only", save it, and open it. The difference seems to be that I can modify the file in that case - I just can't save it. But **this file cannot be edited at all, even if I don't save it.**  And the above "read" operation is treated as a "modification"...

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a document property that I can read in VBA to tell me this is a "cannot modify" file? I am looking for something akin to `ActivePresentation.ReadOnly`, but that is set for a "read only" file, and this is different.
2. Why does the line `If Len(oSl.Tags(tagName)) > 0 Then` get treated as a "modifying file" operation?

It was difficult to reproduce this error, because I really needed to have two users open the same file (saving the file as read-only was not enough) to make it happen. Looking forward to your insights / comments / answers!

Comment: It might suffice to set the presentation's .Saved property to True, but what you're seeing might also be due to as-yet unfixed bugs in PPT (especially 2013).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - thanks for the comment. This is Office 2010. I will try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: A similar problem was reported [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ab3b536a-b76e-44b5-b493-3a28f9ac48d1/cannot-access-powerpoint-object-model-when-file-opened-from-sharepoint?forum=officegeneral). It makes me wonder whether the answer is "it can't be done" (that seemed to be the 'official' Microsoft response). But that, typically, makes me mad.

Comment: The MS guy's response was pretty much useless, I agree. Question: are you seeing different behaviors between files marked RO at the OS level and files that are opened RO because another user's already got the file open first?  Question:  the thread you referenced mentions SharePoint; are you seeing the problem there or even when the file's on a shared network drive?  I'd like to learn more so I can at least report it to some folks I know at MS.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I don't see the problem when I open a file that is marked read-only; only when I am "forced" to open read-only because it is in use. And this is happening on a shared network drive. Reporting this to Microsoft sounds like a great answer... even if it doesn't help me in the short run.

Comment: I've done some more testing (in 2010) and can perfectly repro the problem as you've described it. I've reported it and pointed out that, whatever the intended behavior for examining tags might be, it's clearly a bug that the user can do a Save As but we cannot do it in code.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in this, @SteveRindsberg!